# How to get tabulator validator set data to cell on callback

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I would like to find a way to get the tabulator validation callback to set data to a cell. To explain my use case:

I have a cell I want a user to be able to input data. My custom validator  makes sure the inputted data matches in a list of options. Currently the data inputted needs to be case sensitive, As I would like the data to be entered to follow a certain format.

My goal:
Allow a user to input data such as "bob". It fails validation, and the validation callback sees that there is a lowercase match to "Bob", so the cell value should be "Bob".

I think I am 90% of the way there, I have all the logic in place to set the value on callback, but it looks like I might be breaking tabulator in a bad way. The cell looks like its still in edit mode (but lost focus, with a red box around the cell).

My validator code:

```
 var validCheck = function (cell, value, parameters) {
            return (AllowedVals.map(function (v) { return v.name; 
                })).includes(value); 
        }
```

My validator callback:

```
            validationFailed:function(cell, value, validators){

                if (AllowedVals.map(function (v) { return v.name.toLowerCase(); }).includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                    var match = AllowedVals.filter(function (allowedVal) { return allowedVal.name.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase() });
                    cell.setValue(AllowedVals[0].name);                    
                }
            },
```

After the cell gets updated via the validation callback, i cannot edit the cell anymore, the cellEdited method is never called, and there are plenty (48 in total) of errors in the Chrome Dev Console. I have "Maximum call stack size exceeded" and "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?"

This leads me to believe tabulator is stuck in some sort of validation loop. Can someone help me find the right way to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: I think a better way to go about this is using mutators. I'm still looking into how to use them, but it seems less convoluted than the loop factory I have going on here.

Answer (score 1):

Mutators are the answer here.

I set my validation to check if its a case insensitive match.

```
 var validCheck = function (cell, value, parameters) {
            return (AllowedVals.map(function (v) { return v.name.toLowerCase(); 
                })).includes(value.toLowerCase()); 
        }
```

Then created a mutator to return the correct case if it finds a case insensitive match.

```
var Mutate = function(value, data, type, params, component){

             if (AllowedVals.map(function (v) { return v.name.toLowerCase(); }).includes(value.toLowerCase())) {
                    var match = AllowedVals.filter(function (allowedVal) { return allowedVal.name.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase() });
                     return match[0].name;                    
                }
             else {
                 return value;      
             }
        }
```

In the end it posts the correct data to my server and instantly updates the grid view with the mutated data (Extra Bonus).